# Words along a laurel wreath

Tags: knowledge, word-sequence

These eleven words must be placed along the laurel wreath. One has already been placed.

BOUND,
CLOSED,
COMPANY,
DARK,
GATE,
GREAT,
KING,
LAST,
MANY,
PAST,
WHITE

Hint 1A

> Half of the image component acts as clue toward the answer, the other half is merely aesthetic.

Hint 1B

> The laurel wreath might be made into a clue if it were instead a chain with six links.

Hint 2

> Theoretically, we could add a twelfth word to the puzzle, but there is no word that would meet the puzzle's restrictions.

Hint 3

> A theoretical twelfth word would go between & connect both ends of the laurel, making a ring around the outside.

[image: Image of laurel wreath with 11 spaces for words wrapping around an image of the globe from the NE corner clockwise to the NW corner. The second clockwise space contains the word "GATE"]

Comment: Do you have a source or attribution for this puzzle? Otherwise, it is liable to be closed.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? I created the puzzle from scratch. It wasn't taken from anywhere, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Interesting! I have a hunch as to what this relates to, but I'm not sure I quite see the relationship yet. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Perfect! Carry on, then. Any puzzles taken from external sources require attribution. Self-made puzzles are in the clear! Looks like a fun one!

Comment: Oh, phew! I was having flashbacks to the first time I posted on reddit and got temporarily banned for breaking (I would say bending) the subreddit's posting rules.

Comment: I am pretty sure the words are rot13(sebz puncgre gvgyrf va ybeq bs gur evatf, nf fhttrfgrq ol rnegu orvat va gur zvqqyr). But I am having trouble putting them in order primarily due to rot13(gur puncgre gvgyrq Gur Oynpx Tngr vf Pybfrq), which prevents rot13(hfvat gur svefg vafgnapr va gur yvfg bs puncgref). Is this intended?

Answer (score 6):

One possible answer is:

> From top left around: PAST, COMPANY, CLOSED, WHITE, KING, MANY, BOUND, GREAT, LAST, GATE, DARK

The logic:

> All of the words in the list appear in [chapter titles of The Lord of the Rings](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Portal:The_Lord_of_the_Rings_Chapters) (which is suggested by the image of Earth being in the Middle of the diagram: Middle-Earth). The Lord of the Rings has six books, each of which is broken into a number of chapters between 9 and 12. Sort the chapters first by its chapter number within the book, then the book number, so that the ordering starts: A Long-expected Party (Ch. 1, Bk. 1), Many Meetings (Ch. 1, Bk. 2), The Departure of Boromir (Ch. 1, Bk. 3), etc.

From this list:

> Select the chapters which contain one of the words of the list. Five of these words, namely COMPANY, DARK, GATE, KING and MANY, appear in the titles of two such chapters. The placement of GATE second to last in the string suggests that we select only the LAST instance of each of these words. This selection produces the list above.

Comment: With regards to the wrinkle, rot13(gur cynprzrag bs 'tngr' vf zrnag gb qvfnzovthngr gjb flzzrgevpny fbyhgvbaf, ohg vf abg zrnag gb 'qvfdhnyvsl' yvxr vg jbhyq arrq gb va guvf fbyhgvba).

Comment: Ok, fair. This works & is cleaner logic than your original guess, but it's still not the solution I had in mind. I could add another hint, but I will hold off if you want, because I feel like you are circling in on the solution.

Comment: I'm off to other things in a moment, so I'd go ahead and add the hint in case someone can get the whole way...